# Crash Logging in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to track application crashing in my app. So i looked on internet and got this and it gives comprehensive solution.

http://blog.ike.to/2011/02/02/wp7-application-crash-reporter/

In my case I have My Application Pages In Different Project And All Business Logic In Different Class Library Project.

I also placed this Crashreporter Code Over there. But I am getting error on this line

```
App.Current.UnhandledException += new EventHandler<ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs>(App_UnhandledException);
```

as App.xaml is not in this project. How I can refer that part here or Create its Object of app.xaml and use this line. Because I want to keep seprate this class from my views.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you need to keep your handler code in main app and just recon source of exception and put it in different log files (or what you are use).

Comment: Yes I want to keep handlers in my main app. But I also want to know about obfocusated method and device lock states and unhandled exceptions. So what is best practices to do so.?

Comment: So looks like you need to care that other developer implemented good these libraries for you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5885036/182344.. Or you should hope that guys who implemented your library use some obfuscatory with error handling.. somtehing like - http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/exception-reporting.htm